# how run pyspark shell from docker hosted spark - "Error: pyspark does not support any application options."

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

i am running bitnami/spark stack using [this docker-compose](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/spark/docker-compose.yml).

While it is running fine (i can submit and run pyspark based jobs) i can not use pyspark interactive spell:

i connect to master bash:

`docker exec -it spark-spark-1 bash`

and run pyspark:

```
I have no name!@97797a6ff82f:/opt/bitnami/spark$ pyspark
Error: pyspark does not support any application options.
```

on the other hand i see pyspark installed in `/opt/bitnami/spark/bin`. Running spark works fine.

this seems to be a known problem

https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/38139

or here https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/32710

The same problem seem to exist for official image.

So the question is: it is possible to start pyspark within container?

Is there an alternative solution to get a pyspark working with spark running in docker?